# What causes replays to come out very dark?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Using the built in replay editor, replays look fine (as they do in gameplay):

[image]

But after saving the replay to a file, they come out very dark:

[image]

Note it doesn't look too bad here since it's small, but bring up the fullsize and you'll see the difference. Also here's the full video to see the darkened issue:

This seems to be a reoccurring problem for people: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1875348

What could be the cause?

```
Win7 64bit
6GB RAM
i7 CPU
ATI Radeon HD 5800
1400x900
```

Comment: It sounds like the gamma in-game and the gamma for rendering don't match, although I don't have enough experience with replays to help further than that.

Comment: The issue is there's no gamma or lighting setting for rendering.

Comment: Is the cloaking effect _supposed_ to give you rainbows in your skin? Is the dead ringer supposed to be pink? Does removing the skin help? (Also, damn, that's quite a long capture time on a last point right outside the enemy spawn.)

Comment: With no mods, the problem still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Steam support, this (the codec part) solved it:

> Thank you for contacting Steam Support.
>
> You may wish to select a different rendering output codec.
>
> Note that video compression techniques often rely on reducing the
>   range of colors and brightness used in a frame.
>
> Using a different codec may create better results.
>
> You may also try increasing the Brightness Levels in the in-game Video
>   options menu prior to rendering the replay.
>
> For more information and options, please refer to the TF2 Wiki replay
>   article linked below.
>
> http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Replay
>
> If you have any further questions, please let us know - we will be
>   happy to assist you.

Comment: Could be useful (for posterity) to specify which codec you were using, and which you switched to that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The same forum post you linked to has a possible solution by using [windowed mode](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=22269887&postcount=11).

Other than that, it could be a driver issue - try installing the latest & greatest [ATI drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx).

Also, if you are running dual video cards try disabling one of them.  Dual GPU setups can exhibit weird behaviors.

Comment: I'm already running (borderless) windowed mode and have the latest drivers.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.